# Run thread in main window for both Windows and Linux

Tags: window, wxpython, pygame

I am creating a game to run inside a GUI (text area, button, menu etc) I've created a GUI with wxpython.  I create a panel inside the main window, which runs a pygame thread.

### Problem:

On Windows, the pygame thread runs *perfectly* inside the main window.  But on Linux, the pygame pop up on a new window. How can I set this such that both windows and Linux run the thread in the main window?

### Code:

```
class SDLPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent,ID,tplSize):
        global pygame
        global pygame_init_flag
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID, size=tplSize)
        self.Fit()

        if (sys.platform == 'win32'):
            os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(self.GetHandle())
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
        else:
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'x11'

        #here is where things change if pygame has already been initialized
        #we need to do so again
        if pygame_init_flag:
            #call pygame.init() on subsaquent windows
            pygame.init()
        else:
            #import if this is the first time
            import pygame
        pygame_init_flag = True #make sure we know that pygame has been imported
        pygame.display.init()
        window = pygame.display.set_mode(tplSize)
        self.thread = SDLThread(window)
        self.thread.Start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.thread.Stop()
        print "thread stoped"
        #very important line, this makes sure that pygame exits before we
        #reinitialize it other wise we get errors
        pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem.

In main window we must self.Show()
Idk why in linux the main window must be showed . Same code.
Tks all

Answer (score 0):

This is a disclaimer alert, according to https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=39332, the solution works only with SDL 1.2 and not 2.0.